# How to show the list paragraphs that belong to the user's Company in the django admin form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin

I'm developing a project in Django. I have several registered companies, and all models are based on the company.

```py
#models.py

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class XUser(User):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    card = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(XUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Paragraph(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Now in my admin I define that every user can only see the books of his company.

```py
#admin.py

@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        # return a filtered queryset
        return qs.filter(company=request.user.company)
```

My question is this: When I try to create a Paragraph instance in the django management form, it shows me all the books and I want it to only show me the ones that belong to the user's Company. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by overriding the `get_form` method to change the queryset of `company`:

**admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(Paragraph)
class ParagraphAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['book'].queryset = Book.objects.filter(company=request.user.company)
        return form
```